# How does the requestAnimationFrame method work in the game 2048?

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I found this codepen.io for the game 2048: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMzmae

The game is written in JavaScript with a GameManager, HTMLActuator to create the HTML elements, a ScoreManager to keep track of the score and a KeyboardInputManager to track what is pressed and what to do.

The application uses window.requestAnimationFrame to redraw the window. I was wondering how it does that. When the code actuates, it uses the window.requestAnimationFrame() and inside for each cell in the grid it uses the addTile() method to add each tile to the DOM.

```
 HTMLActuator.prototype.actuate = function (grid, metadata) {
      var self = this;

      window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        self.clearContainer(self.tileContainer);

        grid.cells.forEach(function (column) {
          column.forEach(function (cell) {
            if (cell) {
              self.addTile(cell);
            }
          });
        });

        self.updateScore(metadata.score);

        if (metadata.over) self.message(false); // You lose
        if (metadata.won) self.message(true); // You win!
      });
    };
```

If you look at the addTime() method, it too has a window.requestAnimationFrame method that updates the class with the currentPosition if the tile it's adding had a previousPosition property:

```
   HTMLActuator.prototype.addTile = function (tile) {
      var self = this;

      var element   = document.createElement("div");
      var position  = tile.previousPosition || { x: tile.x, y: tile.y };
      positionClass = this.positionClass(position);

      // We can't use classlist because it somehow glitches when replacing classes
      var classes = ["tile", "tile-" + tile.value, positionClass];
     this.applyClasses(element, classes);

     element.textContent = tile.value;

      if (tile.previousPosition) {
        // Make sure that the tile gets rendered in the previous position first
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
          classes[2] = self.positionClass({ x: tile.x, y: tile.y });
          self.applyClasses(element, classes); // Update the position
        });
      } else if (tile.mergedFrom) {
        classes.push("tile-merged");
        this.applyClasses(element, classes);

        // Render the tiles that merged
        tile.mergedFrom.forEach(function (merged) {
          self.addTile(merged);
        });
      } else {
        classes.push("tile-new");
        this.applyClasses(element, classes);
      }

      // Put the tile on the board
      this.tileContainer.appendChild(element);
    };
```

I guess I'm wondering how does this requestAnimationFrame work to correctly display the tiles when moved? It's building up each tile with the tile information in the grid. Then in addTile() it first uses the tile's previousPosition to build a tile that used to be on the board and creates a class for that position but then it checks if the tile has a previous position and updates the class back to the tile's new position on the grid.

But that only happens in a requestAnimationFrame method for tiles with a previous position and before the method finishes and appends the tile to the tile container in the DOM.

I hope the question makes sense. Are those nested window.RequestAnimationFrame's in the addTile method() called right after the original window.RequestAnimationFrame call in the HTMLActuator.prototype.actuate method so it moves to the new position after an instant and the CSS transition shows it moving?

Comment: I am also confused why you add the mergedFrom tiles back to the board if the tile was merged. How are they able to animate to the new spot then disappear when their coordinates are from their original spots?

Comment: I guess you'd better ask the author on why he designed it like this.